# How do I animate an SVG of the letter X to appear as if it's being drawn?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

[This Codepen](https://codepen.io/stephenbe/pen/bNKpOr) does exactly what I want but I'd like to understand *why* it works the way it does.

I understand the general concept of [line animation](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) and have successfully animated the letter O, which is a singe stroke. However, animating the dash offset from line length down to zero didn't seem to work for the X which has two intersecting strokes. (As you can imagine, I'm building a Tic Tac Toe game here.)

This part CSS of the Codepen's CSS has me stumped:

```css
#path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 430;
  stroke-dashoffset: 800;
  
  animation: x 0.6s linear ;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

#path3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 430;
  stroke-dashoffset: 800;
  
  animation: x 0.6s linear ;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-delay:0.3s;
}

@keyframes x {
  from {
     stroke-dasharray: 430;
  }
  to {
     stroke-dasharray: 400;
  }
}
```

How did they arrive at these values for `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` and why do they work?

### What I Tried

What I tried with my own CSS was to do the same thing I did for my O. `50` being the approximate size of each line:

```
#x-line-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 50;
  stroke-dashoffset: 50;
  animation: draw-x 0.6s linear forwards;
}

#x-line-2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 50;
  stroke-dashoffset: 50;
  animation: draw-x 0.6s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes draw-x {
  from {
     stroke-dasharray: 50;
  }
  to {
     stroke-dasharray: 0;
  }
}
```

I'd like to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the source code of the two lines.

Comment: Try animating the stroke-dashoffset instead. Also the length of the lines is 46.67. I would use a delay equal with the previous animation.

Comment: @enxaneta that worked! Somehow I missed that the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also take advantage of the [`pathLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) attribute.
In short: you can use it to avoid manual stroke-dash length calculation.

From  mdn docs

> The pathLength attribute lets authors specify a total length for the
> path, in user units. This value is then used to calibrate the
> browser's distance calculations with those of the author, by scaling
> all distance computations using the ratio pathLength / (computed value
> of path length).

```css
.stroke {
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  fill: none;
  animation: strokeAni 2s forwards 1;
}

@keyframes strokeAni {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <line pathLength="100" class="stroke" x1="8.5" y1="8.5" x2="41.5" y2="41.5" />
  <line pathLength="100" class="stroke" x1="41.5" y1="8.5" x2="8.5" y2="41.5" style="animation-delay:1s" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <circle class="stroke" pathLength="100" cx="25" cy="25" r="18" transform="rotate(-90) scale(1 -1)" transform-origin="25 25" style="animation-delay:2s; animation-duration:4s;" />
</svg>
```

The above example  needs only a single `@keyframes` rule.
You can delay individual elements animations by adding inline style properties e.g `animation-delay`.